# How do I log a model with metrics and plots in MLRun?

Tags: python, mlops, nuclio, mlrun

I'm training a model using MLRun and would like to log the model using experiment tracking. What kinds of things can I log with the model? I'm specifically looking for metrics (i.e. accuracy, F1, etc.) and plots like loss over time

Answer (score 2):

MLRun has the ability to [automatically log models](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/concepts/auto-logging-mlops.html) with metrics and plots generated and attached.

You will use something like

```py
from sklearn import ensemble
from mlrun.frameworks.sklearn import apply_mlrun

# Get data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = ...

# Pick an ideal ML model
model = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()
    
# Wrap our model with Mlrun features, specify the test dataset for analysis and accuracy measurements
apply_mlrun(model, model_name='my_model', X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test)
    
# Train our model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The result is a model logged in the experiment tracking framework with metrics, code, logs, plots, etc. available per run. The MLRun auto-logger supports standard ML frameworks such as SciKit-Learn, TensorFlow (and Keras), PyTorch, XGBoost, LightGBM, and ONNX.

Alternatively, you can log something manually using the MLRun `context` object that is available during the run. This lets you do things like `context.log_model(...)`, `context.log_dataset(...)` or `context.logger.info("Something happened")`. More info on the MLRun execution context can be found [here](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/concepts/mlrun-execution-context.html).